# Powerpivot-Flag first occurence depending on what user filters

Tags: powerpivot

In power pivot, I am trying to figure out how to tag the first occurrence of a visit, based upon what a user filters. For example, if they are looking at calendar year 2014 below is the data.  Distinctcount works if you don't care about the time period in which the first count occurs.
[image: CY2014]
If a user filters to March 2014 only, the would see 
the following:

[image: March2014]

Answer (score 1):

this seems tricky at first, but can be done very easily with DAX:

```
=
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Visits[VisitID] ),
        ALL ( Visits[VisitID] ),
        ALL ( Visits[AdmitDate] )
    )
        - MAX ( [VisitID] )
        = 0,
    1,
    0
)
```

What this does is very straightforward - it removes the filter on both *VisitID* and *AdmitDate*, and by doing so it calculates the minimum for every single *Patient ID*. Then it subtracts MAX of *VisitID* for a given row. **If the difference equals to 0 (that means this is the first visit), then the value is set to 1**, otherwise the value is set to 0.

I have named this measure *Check* and if you then add it to your table, the result should look like this:

[image]

Works well with filtering too (in this case Filter is set on *Month* = 3):

[image]

**Alternative approach using RANKX in case of multiple columns**

Also, [RANKX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492185.aspx) could be used to achieve this - it seems to be a bit more flexible solution, however I am not sure what would be the performance in a very large dataset.

```
=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Visits[PatientID] ),
    IF (
        RANKX (
            FILTER (
                ALLSELECTED ( Visits ),
                Visits[PatientID] = MAX ( Visits[PatientID] )
            ),
            [MIN Visit],
            ,
            1,
            DENSE
        )
            = 1,
        1,
        0
    ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Visits[PatientID] )
)
```

This works perfectly even if you filter any column. It's a bit complex to understand, but play around a bit with it and also check the linked documentation. What the formula basically does is **dynamic RANK across group that is determined by [PatiendID]**.

The *Visit ID* is **the key item being ranked** - you have to use a new measure which I named *MIN Visit*:

```
=MIN([VisitID])
```

The very first IF checks, if the current row is a *Total Row*, and if so it performs a different calculation to get the total of patients with first visits (by counting distinct values of *Patiend ID*).

I have updated the source Excel file as well. Here is the [link (2013 version)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvpoovpj375x6eb/FirstDateDax-1-0.xlsx?dl=0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is fabulous!  But wouldn't the first part of the formula, where you say it is taking the minimium for every patientid be Min(Visits[PatientID])?

Comment: Hey Sarah - try it and you will see the results. I think the important distinction here is that you are looking for lowest (MIN) Visit ID for each Patient ID. I hope my explanation makes sense :-)

Comment: So I did try it and I see what you are doing now. However, what if I have many more fields in my dataset than just those I showed in the example?  I actually have probably 50 columns of data, so would I have to use something that says ALLEXCEPT?

Comment: Sarah, I tried ALLEXCEPT and there is one drawback - it won't reflect filters selected by users in Pivot Table (it will always take all data - in the example I shared, if user selects Month = 3, then he would see only zeroes in column Check).

Comment: That's why I used this approach - let me check any alternative solution so that you won't have to write down all the columns.

Comment: So Sarah, I tried different approach with RANKX and now it works perfectly even if you filter anything. It's a bit complex to understand, but play around a bit with it and also check the linked documentation. What the formula basically does is dynamic rank across group that is determined by [PatiendID].

Comment: This works! Amazing. My only question now is how do I get it to sum up? So if I want to sum the rows that a 1 is appearing (in this case to show a total of 2), how do I do that since it is a measure and not a column? I'm blanking, but otherwise this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Updated the formula - can you verify it works correctly on your data? The very first IF checks, if the current row is a Total Row, and if so it performs a different calculation to get the total of patients with first visits (by counting distinct values of Patiend ID).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to ultimately see.

If you just want the first visit date, you would add a calculated field such as:

```
CALCULATE( FIRSTDATE( 'Date'[Date]), FILTER( Fact, Fact[AdmitDate] >= MIN( 'Date'[Date] ) ) )
```

IF you want to count the number of patients by date where it was their first visit, based on how the data is sliced, that gets much more complicated.